# how to print thead of the table on each print page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

my table contain large number of dynamic rows when i print or print preview it i get only table thead on only first page using window.print() function ..but i want table thead on each print page... help?

```
<div id="printablediv" >
<div style="padding:8px;font-size: 13px;">
    <center>
        <?php
        $sumMul = 0;
        $sumBil = 0;
        ?>
        <?php $total = $total_ni = $total_aa = $total_pe = $total_bak = $total_cnt = 0; ?>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="font-size: 13px;" >
            <thead id="head">
                <tr bgcolor="#333333"   style="color:#black;font-weight: bold;">
                    <th  width="100" align="center">Donor</th>
                    <th  width="100" align="center">Loan No.</th>
                    <th  width="120" align="center">Value Date</th>
                    <th  width="90" align="center">Curr</th>
                    <th  width="150" align="center">Multilateral</th>
                    <th  width="150" align="center">Bilateral</th>
                    <th  width="150" align="center">Forex</th>
                    <th  width="150" align="center">Multilateral</th>
                    <th  width="150" align="center">Bilateral</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php $previousValue = $list[0]->LOAN_ID; ?>
            <?php $flag = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($list as $key => $val): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $val->EX_DONOR_CODE; ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $val->LOAN_ID; ?></td>
                    <td  align="center"><?php echo $val->VALUE_DATE; ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?php echo $val->TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE; ?></td>
                    <td align="right"><?php
                        if ($val->DONOR_TYPE == 'MULTILATERL') {
                            $sumMul += $val->COMMIT_CUR_AMT;
                            echo $val->COMMIT_CUR_AMT;
                        }
                        ?></td>
                    <td align="right"><?php
                        if ($val->DONOR_TYPE == 'BILATERAL') {
                            $sumBil += $val->COMMIT_CUR_AMT;
                            echo $val->COMMIT_CUR_AMT;
                        }
                        ?></td>
                    <td align="right"><?php //reports::report1_5Forex($val->TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE ,$val->VALUE_DATE) ?></td>
                    <td align ="right"></td>
                </tr>
<?php $previousValue = $val->LOAN_ID ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Print" id="prt" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />
</div>
```

i got javascript code here:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divID) {
    var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML =
            "<body>" +
            divElements + "</body>";
    $('#prt').hide();
    window.print();
    $('#prt').show();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible.

Comment: i got mpdf method but its time consuming and hard and slow processing too..

Comment: Yes that is certainly possible but it is not a javascript solution...

Comment: can we count print page using js?? so that i can append coustom head to per print page...
is there any jquery pdf generator?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `thead` and `tbody` to print the table header on each page http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD

> Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or
>   more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements,
>   respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling
>   of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. *When long
>   tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be
>   repeated on each page that contains table data.*

If this doesn't work, the browser vendors doesn't implement the standard correctly.